# Converting escaped text to html in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I used `$.get` and received data like

```
'<option value=\"US-ID\" >Idaho<\/option>\n  <option value=\"US-IL\" >Illinois<\/option>\n  <option value=\"US-IN\" >Indiana<\/option>\n  <option value=\"US-KS\" >Kansas<\/option>\n'
```

I want to use `$(...).html(html_data)` how do I make the data I get into html data that I can use?

what I'm getting when `$(...).html(data)`

http://jsfiddle.net/9WeUv/

Don't know if this matters, but `console.log(data)`:

`'...data...'`

whereas `console.log('regular_string')`:

`regular_string` // no quotes

Comment: Where does the string come from? What's adding the `\` characters?

Comment: Maybe an Ajax request?

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with:

```
var html_data = '<option value=\"US-ID\" >Idaho<\/option>\n  <option value=\"US-IL\" >Illinois<\/option>\n  <option value=\"US-IN\" >Indiana<\/option>\n  <option value=\"US-KS\" >Kansas<\/option>\n';

$('#select_element_id').html(html_data);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/45CYX/

After your edit:

Sorry, isn't the string you've received the one you wrote on top? In your jsFiddle you do not have any JS code, just some text in a `select` tag - which is not what you are saying in the question.

Comment: for some reason when I did it, the <\/option> and \n, etc would be there.

Comment: As far as I know the `html()` function in jQuery will take care of the deserialisation of the string for you.

Comment: well the thing is `console.log(data)` gives `'...'` where for a regular string `console.log('foo')` gives `foo`. Don't know if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you grabbed the html from an ajax call and want to add it to the body.

```
$newSelect = $("<select></select>").html(html_data);
$(document.body).append($newSelect);
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2 - Creates DOM elements on the fly from the provided string of raw HTML.